# camera intent pictures only saved in camera album

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

Ive been trying to look around couldn't find the exact answer for this.

problem is every time i save the file from my camera, on the result
i get the file IN the Camera Album and not in any other album
and ONLY if i delete the pictures from the camera album the appear in another album that i can then suddenly see, can someone help me fix this ? 
why is this happening ?

i have a camera intent i call like this>

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_ONE);
                }
```

then on my on activity result:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        WorkingOrdersModel myWorkorder = WorkingOrdersModel.getWorkorderById(selectedWorkorderId);

        // get images
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bitmapFromCamera = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_ONE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            createDirectoryAndSaveFile(bitmapFromCamera, myWorkorder.workorderWifiSSID.toLowerCase()+"_one.png");

            cameraImageOne.setImageBitmap(bitmapFromCamera);

        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_TWO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            createDirectoryAndSaveFile(bitmapFromCamera, myWorkorder.workorderWifiSSID.toLowerCase()+"_two.png");

            cameraImageTwo.setImageBitmap(bitmapFromCamera);

        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_THREE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            createDirectoryAndSaveFile(bitmapFromCamera, myWorkorder.workorderWifiSSID.toLowerCase()+"_three.png");

            cameraImageThree.setImageBitmap(bitmapFromCamera);

        }
    }
```

and finally the saving process

```
/**
     * saves an image from camera in a spacific place
     * @param imageToSave
     * @param fileName
     */
    private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/WINTouch");

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/WINTouch/");
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/WINTouch/"), fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Camera saves the taken picture as .jpg image in .../DCIM/Camera which you then, in the Gallery app, see in a Camera folder.

What you are doing is saving a thumbnail of this picture to a different location without informing the MediaStore about it.

You much better change your intent a bit so the Camera app will store the picture in the path you provide. Google for EXTRA_STREAM EXTRA_OUTPUT?

Comment: thnx, can you give an example on how to use such intent ?